# why this code do not redirect the page

Tags: php, sql

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);

    include("../../php/open.php");// db-connection



        print_r($_REQUEST);
         if(isset($_REQUEST['form1']))
          {  


            if(!empty($_POST['description'])){

                $id=$_REQUEST['id'];

                $field_name = $_REQUEST['field_name'];

                $paragraph1=$_REQUEST['description'];

                $text = $paragraph1; 

                $query ="UPDATE website_data SET field_value = '$text', field_name= '$field_name' WHERE id = '$id';";

                $result=mysql_query($query);
                if($result==true){
                    $url="index.php?page=content_edit";
                    die('<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="' . $url . '";</script>');
                }
              }
              else{
                  echo "<script>alert('page body can not be empty')</script>";
              }
         }

    ?>
```

and shows the output....

[image: Output screenshot]

Comment: Perhaps an idea is to set **error reporting** to 1 such that it shows the correct errors.

Comment: 404 is a not found issue, as in, your file was not found... does the path look ok to you? is the file there? etc

Comment: I think path is correct and file is the right place. I checked it more times. When I update the content it's update successfully but do not redirect the page and show this message

Comment: why, in PHP using JS redirect if u can use pure PHP redirect via header as shown in Answer 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use this:

```
   if($result==true){
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href='index.php?page=content_edit'
  </script>";
              }
```

Comment: still same problem man but content update successfully@ Ajay Malhotra

Comment: what is the output, you are getting?

Comment: if($result==true){
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href='index.php?page=content_edit'
  </script>";
die();
              }

Comment: Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on thereferring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.19

but content update in the webpage successfully @Ajay Malhotra

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use php header function to redirect, but don't forget to remove print_r from the top.

instead of

```
 die('<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="' . $url . '";</script>');
```

use

```
header('location : '.$url);
```

Comment: if I use "header" instead of "die" and remove print_r from the top it update the content but steel do not redirect the page. it shows a blank page now @D. Pachauri

Comment: use exit; just after header, it will stop script executing further.

Comment: still same problem@ D. Pachauri